# Query regarding the function of an infinitive

Tags: infinitives

What function does the infinitive serve in the following sentence?

> It is too early *to talk* about that thing.

Comment: Its function is that of **complement** of the adjective "early".

Comment: A to plus an infinitive expresses purpose in English.

Comment: Note that it is not licensed by "early" itself, but by the "too" that modifies "early"

Comment: Right. _Too_ in the construction _too `Adj` to `VP`_ is a negative; the construction means 'so `Adj` that not `VP`', though of course that idiom requires a tensed VP and not an infinitive. Hence, _It's too early to talk about that_ means we should not talk about that now. As for the function of the infinitive, it's what gets negated by _too_; what other functions do you have to choose from?

Comment: Note the near-paraphrases 'To talk about that [thing] would be inappropriate for the time being.' /  'Discussing that would be inappropriate for the time being.' While 'function' must be read in the syntactic sense on ELU, the main thrust of the sentence is to state that [discussion of X[] needs to be postponed]. The original emphasises the over-earliness.

Answer (score 1):

> *It is too early to talk about that thing.*

The function of the infinitival clause is that of indirect **complement** of the adjective "early". It's indirect because although it is complement of the head "early", it is licensed by the "too" that modifies "early". In other words, although it is licensed by "too" it is a dependent of "early" not directly of "too".

"Too" expresses a degree that exceeds the maximum or upper bound consisting, in this case, of the maximum at which one can talk about that thing. It is early to a degree higher than the maximum at which one can or should talk about that thing: it follows that one can't or shouldn't talk about that thing now, hence it has a negative implication.